# Pass slider value through scene using direct

Tags: android, ios, iphone, lua, coronasdk

I'm looking for a way to pass a variable through scenes using the director class.

I saw several questions similar to mine, but I haven't solved my problem.

The code is:

```
local function sliderListener( event )

    local value = event.value
    local noise = value

end

local slider = widget.newSlider
{
 top = _H/2+90,
 left = _W/2-100,
 width = 200,
 value = 70,  
 listener = sliderListener
}
```

I would pass the "noise" variable into the "game" scene, which is called using

```
director:changeScene("game")
```

I tried to code

```
director:changeScene(noise, "game")
```

but Corona returns that the scene name MUST be a string.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
director:changeScene({noise=noise}, "game")
```

The first parameter must either be a scene_name or a table containing parameters